# How to compile/link using an alternate GCC build

Tags: gcc

I have built and installed a newer version of gcc, and want to use that to build some programs. I am unsure of the proper procedure.

My Plan is to,

- Use `update-alternatives` to switch between standard gcc and my gcc-5.3.0 and add `g++`, `c++`, `g77` as slaves. (Or any other method to create symlinks to the all the gcc-related executables at a standard location -- Ex. `/usr/local/bin`)
- Add the `gcc-5.3.0/lib` (and `gcc-5.3.0/libexec`?) to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Any other things I need to do? when compiling/linking and running those programs?

Comment: This is a question for askubuntu, for values of ubuntu equal to yourdistro.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ubuntu, just asking how to compile and link properly with a non-standard gcc build. I am on SL6 (CentOS6)

Comment: I said ubuntu==yourdistro didn't I? update-alternatives looks awfully distro-specific.

Comment: `update-alternatives` is available in RHEL systems, SUSE and Ubuntu, which covers a fair bit of linux distro by usage. In anycase, updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: You *may* have to update your `ld` (binutils). Figured it out literally today, the hard way. Programs compiled with new gcc and linked with system ld all crashed on startup.

Comment: OK my bad, never used this command, I'm a gentoo victim.

Answer (score 3):

Most build tools and evironments allow redefining used compilers. For example, typical Makefile uses variables CC for C code and CXX for C++ code. If you run `make` for a usual compiling, you can use instead something like

```
env CXX='/opt/gcc-5.3.0/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath=/opt/gcc-5.3.0/lib' make
```

this also changes used linker, because typically the same C compiler is used for a linker driver.

Details will differ on implementation, but this shows the main path.

Such redefining of CC, CXX also affects `configure` from autotools and a bunch of similar tools.

For more help you should specify the build tools used in products you compile.

Comment: didn't know what `-rpath` was! Thanks!